# XAMPP/PHP on Windows

Tags: windows, php, xampp, windows-command-prompt

I am running XAMPP on Windows Vista.  XAMPP is a ~one year old install with all default options.

I wrote a script in PHP that will do a web crawl and place data in mysql. I placed `set_time_limit(36000)` in the PHP-source code so that the script will not time out. However, because I am launching the script by directing my browser to the PHP file, it seems that the browser (Chrome and Firefox) times out; and then the script stops (i.e. the script runs fine for about a minute and then stops).

Questions:

1. I don't understand if it is possible to run php from the command line with my current configuration. In the cmd prompt, I typed: `php -v` and got `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.
2. If question 1 is true, how do I run PHP from the command prompt? Otherwise, what else can I do that won't cause a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't added PHP to the `PATH` environment variable in Windows. See [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) for general instructions on getting PHP to work from the command line on Windows. Basically, if you want to use PHP from the command line, you need to add the directory containing the PHP executable (probably `C:\xampp\php` in your case) to your `PATH` variable. Take a look at [this guide](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for instructions on how to make changes to your `PATH` variable.
2. At the moment, you should be able to run PHP from the command prompt by typing `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` but once you've correctly set the `PATH` variable as in step 1 above, you should be able to simply type `php` at the command prompt.

To address the issue of PHP timing out when you run your script from a browser, it's unlikely to be an issue caused by your browser. There are two separate `php.ini` configuration files; one applies to the command-line instance of PHP, and the other applies to the instance of PHP that Apache uses, so make sure you've changed the correct file. Another thing to bear in mind is that Apache must be restarted for the configuration change to take effect; your best bet is to simply restart the entire stack.

Finally, is there any particular reason you're using XAMMP rather than WAMP? Unless you're making use of the Perl programming language, I suggest you rather download the [WAMP installer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), which is fully integrated and will setup all of the required environmental variables for you, and comes with great community support.

**Edit:** I've just noticed that you didn't actually mention changing any settings in your `php.ini` file, so I think this is probably your problem with the timeouts. In your `php.ini` file you'll find a setting for `max_execution_time` which is specified in seconds. Change this to a value that you think will more accurately allow your script to finish processing, for example, set it to `max_execution_time = 300` to allow your scripts to run for a maximum of 5 minutes before timing out. Again, remember to restart Apache after making this change.

For the record, performing any sort of web crawling with a PHP script called from a browser is a terrible idea. You should rather  run this as a console application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run php from the command prompt.  You'll either need to navigate within your XAMPP install folder to where the `php.exe` lives, or add that directory to your PATH environmental variable.

I have an old installation of WAMP, and found it at `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe`:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0>php.exe -v
PHP 5.3.0 (cli) (built: Jun 29 2009 21:25:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```